# Java execute jar which depends on other jar from command line

Tags: java, command-line, jar

I have an application that uses an external jar. I used eclipse and it works fine. I export as jar from eclipse, having created a Manifest file that has as Class-Path: ./cab.v1.jar
I place both jars in the same directory.
I run in command line:
java -jar myApp.jar

and get **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** for the classes in the cab.v1.jar (the other jar)
Have also tried java -cp . -jar myApp.jar but no success.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the [documentation for the Manifest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) it does not use a `./` for relative directories.  Try it just with:

```
Class-Path: cab.v1.jar
```

Note that the `-cp` option is ignored when using `-jar`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it, did not work but then extracted jar and saw that eclipse is not using my placing the class-path in the maninifest file. Did it manually and it works. Any idea why eclipse does this?

Comment: You must use Export -> Runnable Jar for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `-jar` option the classpath is ignored. You could start the application by

```
java -cp jar1.jar:jar2.jar mainclass
```

The class path separator ':' is ';' on windows.

Comment: Tried as you said:
java -cp cab.v1.jar -jar myApp.jar
but still same error. Note that both jars are in the same directory

Comment: @user38706 I wrote that you can't use -jar and -cp together. Here are several options: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/classpath.html

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Anyway I extracted jar and saw that eclipse is not using my placing the class-path in the manifest file. Did it manually and it works. Any idea why eclipse does this?