# How to compile and execute java using jar in cmd?

Tags: java

I created one java file then i converted into jar now i want to use it in another java class how to import that jar and how to compile and execute.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java execute jar which depends on other jar from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509457/java-execute-jar-which-depends-on-other-jar-from-command-line)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a "library" class `pkg/LibClass.java`:

```
package pkg;

public class LibClass {
    public static void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

**Compile and create a jar file:**

```
$ javac pkg/LibClass.java 
$ jar cvf lib.jar pkg/LibClass.class
added manifest
adding: pkg/LibClass.class(in = 404) (out= 284)(deflated 29%)
```

(creates a `lib.jar` in the current directory)

**Create an application that uses the library:**

```
import pkg.LibClass;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LibClass.sayHello();
    }
}
```

**Compile and run the application using `lib.jar`:**

```
$ javac -cp lib.jar MainClass.java 
$ java -cp lib.jar:. MainClass
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make that jar file available in classpath at compile time and runtime when that another java file is being compiled/executing

Answer (score 0):

Set the jar in your class path or pass as an argument and compile or execute -

Compile - `javac -classpath your.jar other.java`

Execute - `java -classpath your.jar other`